# How to efficiently switch arguments in vim

Tags: vim

I come upon one scenario when editing a file in vim and I still haven't found a way to do it quickly in vim way. When editing a call of a function, I offently put my arguments in a wrong order.

```
anyFunction(arg2, arg1)
```

When arriving on this situation, I have to find arg2 / delete it / append it before the ')' / deal with the ', ' / etc.

Isn't it a better way to this task quickly ? I am open to any idea (macro/ shortcut / plugin) even if I'd rather have a 'vim only' way of doing this

Comment: Same question, different answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1270278) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3490897).

Comment: Indeed, sorry I didn't find those answer on my previous search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things:

1. A *text object* to quickly select an argument (as they aren't always that simple like in your example). [argtextobj plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2699) (my improved fork [here](https://github.com/inkarkat/argtextobj.vim)) does this.
2. Though you can use delete + visual mode + paste + go back + paste, a plugin to swap text makes this much easier. My [SwapText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4971) or the already mentioned [exchange plugin](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) both do that job.

Comment: Thanks for sharing yet another great plugin, it works like a charm

Comment: I have `myfunc(wgs84, self.projection)`. Pressing `cxia` on `wgs84` and then again `cxia` on `self.projection` works; however, if I press `.` on `self.projection` instead, e.g. on the `r` of `projection`, it results in `myfunc(rojec, self.pwgs84tion)`. Isn't it supposed to work with the dot? This problem is both with the original and your fork.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides: Hm, works for me; do you have repeat.vim installed?!

Comment: I tried installing `repeat.vim`. It still doesn't work. Do I need to also execute some kind of command? I tried `:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Exchange", v:count)` but it doesn't seem to work properly. (Are you using SwapText or exchange? I'm trying with exchange.)

Comment: @AntonisChristofides: Exchange. With SwapText, you have to do `dia` followed by `<Leader>xia`; you cannot use repeat there.

Answer (score 3):

put this mapping in your _vimrc.

```
 " gw : Swap word with next word 
 nmap <silent> gw :s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<cr><c-o><c-l>
```

then in normal mode with the cursor anywhere in arg1 type gw to swap parameters

```
 anyFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

Explanation:-

arg1 the separator (here a comma) and arg2 are put into regexp memories 1 2 3

the substitute reverses them to 3 2 1

Control-O return to last position

Control-L redraw the screen

Note that the separator is any non-alphanumeric character or string e,g whitespace

Comment: Only seems to work when the cursor is at the start of arg1. Still, very nice one-liner!

Answer (score 3):

I actually made a plugin to deal with a exact situation called [argumentative.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative). (Sorry for the plug.)

Argumentative.vim provides the following mappings:

- `[,` and `],` motions which will go to the previous or next argument
- `<,` and `>,` to shift an argument left or right
- `i,` and `a,` argument text objects. e.g. `da,`, `ci,` or `yi,`

So with this plugin you move to the argument in question and then do a `<,` or `>,` as many times as needed. It can also take a count e.g. `2>,`.

If you have Tim Pope's excellent [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin installed `<,` and `>,` become repeatable with the `.` command.

Comment: I'm curious why `,`? Edit: I guess because function arguments are delimited by commas.

Comment: @FDinoff Great question. I wanted something mnemonic and/or related to moving arguments. First I thought about using `a` however the boundary motions, `]a`, would collide with Tim Pope's unimpaired. Which is not only do I use but is a popular. Next up was `p` for parameter but again the boundary motion bothered me because the `]p` is taken. So I settled on `,` as arguments are delimited by commas. The other benefit of using `,` is shift argument commands, `>,`, is meaningless where as `>a` would pause because the `>` operator is waiting for a possible text object.

Comment: I stated that `>a` would pause while that is true. I probably would have changed it to `>aa` and `>ia`. However as stated above the boundary motions would still be a concern

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a plugin: vim-exchange for that:

https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for a regular expression search and replace.

You want to find "anyFunction(", then swap anything up to the ',' with anything from the ',' to the ')'. This is fairly straightforward, using `[^,]*` for "anything up to the ','" and `[^)]*` for "anything up to the ')'". Use `\(...\)` to capture each thing, and `\1`, `\2` to refer to those things in the replacement:

```
:s#anyFunction(\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^)]*\)#anyFunction(\2, \1#g
```

Note how I use `\s*` to allow any whitespace between the "anyFunction(" and the first thing, and also between the ',' and the second thing.

If you want this to be able to span multiple lines, you can use `\_s` instead of `\s`, and capture the whitespace if you want to maintain the multi-line format:

```
:s#anyFunction(\(\_s*\)\([^,]*\),\(\_s*\)\([^)]*\)#anyFunction(\1\4,\3\2#g
```

There is also a multi-line variant of `[...]` collections, for example `\_[^,]` meaning "anything (even a new line) except for a ',' " which you could use in the pattern if your use case demands it.

For details, consult the help topics for: `/\s`, `/\_s`, `/\1`, `/\(`, and `/[`.

If you want a more general-purpose mapping to use at every location, you can use the cursor position in your regular expression, rather than keying off the function name. The cursor position in a regular expression is matched using `\%#` as demonstrated here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Exchanging_adjacent_words

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Peter Rincker suggested (Argumentative), [sideways](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/sideways.vim) also does what you describe.

Comment: Does `splitjoin` really do this? I think it's doing something completely different.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. I should have put `sideways` in there. Thanks for noticing, edited :).